# String modification works in jQuery 1.6.4 but not 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do 2 things to a string:

- Remove first character ($ Symbol).
- Put the decimal place and following figures (.00) in a span with the class "cents".

This is my code, however while it works on jQuery 1.6.4, the client is running jQuery 1.3.2
How do i fix this?

much appreciated.

```
<span class="price">$90.00</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".price").html(function (i, html) {
        return html.replace(/(\.\d+)$/,'<span class="cents">$1</span>').slice(1)
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: Fiddle: http://goo.gl/79EvZw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `html()` method in jQuery that accepts a function was added in version 1.4.

In version 1.3, you could only pass an HTML string into this function.

V1.0 to V1.3

```
.html( htmlString )
```

v1.4

```
.html( htmlString )
.html( function(index, oldhtml) )
```

To get the same behavior in jQuery 1.3, you could do the following:

```
$(".price").each(function(index, elem) {
    var price = $(elem);
    var oldHtml = price.html();
    var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/(\.\d+)$/,'<span class="cents">$1</span>').slice(1);
    price.html(newHtml);
});
```

Comment: If there will definitely be several .price elements, how do i go about it?

Sorry i'm fairly new to this

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="price">$90.00</div>
<div class="price">$100.00</div>
<div class="price">$30.22</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".price").each(function () {
        var div = $(this);
        var split = div.html().split('.');
        var decimal = split[1];
        var dollars = split[0].replace('$','');
        div.html(dollars);
        div.append($("<span classs='cents'>."+decimal+"</span>"));
    });
</script>
```